# How to implement feedback loop for PLL in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, feedback-loop

I am trying to implement PLL demodulator for FM signal in Matlab, without using Simulink.

```
(FM Signal) >----Multiply---Loop Filter------> (Demodulated signal)
                     |                    |
                     ^                    V
                     |--------VCO---------|
```

My plan is to use above configuration. I have `filter`, `VCO` as functions, now I should combine them in a feedback mechanism. What kind of code structure should I use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your input (FM) signal in a vector U, then something along these lines will work if your functions act on one sample at a time.

```
N = length(U);
v = 0; % initial value for v

for n = 1:N

    x = U(n) * v;
    y = loop_filter(x);
    v = vco(y);

    % store output
    Y(n) = y;

end
```

It won't be fast, but that may not be your concern, here.

Comment: possibly helpful hint: the loop_filter function needs to make use of a persistent variable to keep the filter state at each new instance of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: [Simulating phase locked loops (PLLs) with MATLAB](http://aaronscher.com/phase_locked_loop/matlab_pll.html)